# improper output of synchronization in java

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized

In the code, the thread output is not properly synchronized. The output should be the numbers in increasing order.

here is the code

```
public class Prog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread a = new Thread(new Writer(), "A");
        Thread b = new Thread(new Writer(), "B");
        Thread c = new Thread(new Writer(), "C");
        a.start();
        b.start();
        c.start();
    }

    static class Writer implements Runnable {

        private static int count;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (count < 5) {
                show();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }

        private synchronized void show() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":\t" + ++count);
        }
    }
}
```

---

One output of this code is:

```
B:  2
B:  4
C:  3
A:  2
B:  5
```

---

whereas expected output is:

```
B:  1
B:  2
C:  3
A:  4
B:  5
```

---

*What am I missing? Please help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Writer` synchronizes (implicitly) on itself - so you have three writers and three separate locks (no real synchronization between them can occur).

If you change the `show` method to static, the writers will synchronize on the `Writer` class instead - this way all the writers will share the lock and be synchronized with each other.

Comment: Do you know, roughly, how Java synchronization works? I don't know which parts need deeper explaining.